# passing parameters to module.exports in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have the following code for implemetation of nodejs a rest api.
**app.js**

```
var connection = require('./database_connector');    
connection.initalized();  //guys connection is i want to pass a connection varible to the model
var peson_model = require('./models/person_model')(connection); //this not working
var app = express();
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyparser.json());
app.get('/persons/', function(req, res) {
    person_model.get(res); // retrive get results
});
// .............express port and listen
```

`person_model.js` is a model class that is supposed to retrieve based on the http verb. For example `person.get` retrieves the following and currently has a single method as follow.

```
function Person(connection) {
    this.get = function (res) {
        connection.acquire(function(err, con) {
            con.query('select * from person limit 3', function(err, result) {
                con.release();
                console.log("get called");
                res.send(result);
            });
        });
    };
}
// ** I want to pass a connection variable to the model
module.exports = new Person(connection);
```

In the code above, `var peson_model = require('./models/person_model')(connection);` is not working.

How do I pass the connection variable and export the module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you return a function from your export, you can pass your parameter.

```
module.exports = function(connection) {
    return new Person(connection);
};
```

You will need to set `this.connection` and use that inside your function though.

Comment: is there any means that i can pass connection varible implicit not explicit meaning rather than tp share it accross models every time i want it to be application wide . for once created. i greatly appreciated the answer

Comment: How do you send the correct error message if the user forgets to include (connection) when issuing require('./lib.js')? I tried putting an "if connection === undefined then throw" in the function as you have above and the throw isn't executed...

Comment: Hi from where does this `connection` come ?